# SQL - Stripping a string and using it in a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a SQL query issue given to me which i'm struggling to resolve:

It currently brings back 6710445 rows but i need to apply further conditions based on a particular string field.

```
SELECT 
 Table1.ExampleColumn1 -- (ID) 
,Table1.ExampleColumn2
,Table2.ExampleColumn3
,Table2.ExampleColumn4
,Table3.ExampleColumn5
,Table3.ExampleColumn6

,Table1.StringField

  FROM [Example Database].[dbo].[Table1] AS Table1

  INNER JOIN [Example Database].[dbo].[Table2]  AS Table2
    ON Example = Example

  INNER JOIN [Example Database].[dbo].[Table3] AS Table3
    ON Example = Example

  WHERE Month BETWEEN 201304 AND 201603
    AND (Age < 19)
```

The above `'Table1.StringField'` has the following type codes displayed as a string in each the rows: `"||J183,Y752,J374,Y752."`

I also have a reference table (Call it 'Ref1') with 514 of these codes displayed individually, which has no other fields in the table whatsoever.

So what i need to be able to do is find rows from the query above which has any of values from the 'Ref1' displayed anywhere within 'Table1.StringField' individual rows, and if not to not include that row in the results set.

I tried to strip down the 'StringField' column of the comma's and "||" but it didn't work as well as i hoped and ended up bringing back over 30M rows.

Any ideas on how to do this? Preferably so it's efficient and doesn't make the user wait 10 minutes just to query it?

Comment: The best solution would be to stop storing delimited data. It is real mess to work with and the performance is going to suffer. There are some excellent string splitters out there. Here is my personal favorite. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ And some other excellent choices here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings If you are on 2016 or Azure you can use STRING_SPLIT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: Hi Sean, this is very true. Unfortunately this is my organisations current approach and would require a complete overhaul to change this at the source. So far I've tried to avoid stripping it and storing it in another table as there is the issue of there being a lot of rows with many codes displayed in each value so stripping this out to would result in massive amounts of rows in a many to many relationship.

Comment: Well...parsing this into normalized data is better than storing it like this. Millions of rows in a properly normalized table is not a big deal at all. It is certainly better than continuously splitting fewer rows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you half way there... I also agree with Sean Lange's comment about not storing delimited data to begin with but I'm assuming the OP already knows this. You can also pivot/unpivot this data to achieve this as well. This is probably the most brute force way of doing sort of what you're looking to do.

```
--DROP TABLE #Table
--DROP TABLE #Ref
CREATE TABLE #Table (Col VARCHAR(MAX))
CREATE TABLE #Ref (Code VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #Table (Col) VALUES ('A123,B234,C345'),('A123'),('C345')
INSERT INTO #Ref (Code) VALUES ('A123'),('B234')

SELECT * FROM #Table
SELECT * FROM #Ref

SELECT DISTINCT t.Col
FROM #Table t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(r.Code, t.Col) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [ItsHere] FROM #Ref r) oa
WHERE oa.ItsHere = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is join your query to the `Ref1` table on `Table1.StringField = Ref1.Ref_1_value` and then exclude the `Table1` rows that don't match any `Ref_1_value`.  Like this:

```
SELECT 
Table1.ExampleColumn1 -- (ID) 
,Table1.ExampleColumn2
,Table2.ExampleColumn3
,Table2.ExampleColumn4
,Table3.ExampleColumn5
,Table3.ExampleColumn6

,Table1.StringField

FROM [Example Database].[dbo].[Table1] AS Table1

    INNER JOIN [Example Database].[dbo].[Table2]  AS Table2
    ON Example = Example

    INNER JOIN [Example Database].[dbo].[Table3] AS Table3
    ON Example = Example

    INNER JOIN [Example Database].[dbo].[Ref1] as Ref1
    ON Table1.StringField = Ref1.Ref_1_value

WHERE Month BETWEEN 201304 AND 201603
AND (Age < 19)
AND Ref1.Ref_1_value is not null
```

Comment: Hi Rominus, thank-you for your response on this. Unfortunately this will not work though, the REF table values are also single codes each like "J183" whereas the 'StringField' column is delimited data such as  "||J183,Y752,J374,Y752.". So Table1 has a one (ID) to many (Codes) relationship from within a single row. Whereas the ref table is just a list of 500 codes with no ID or anything so specific to join on.

Comment: @Marcus Ah, I see. In that case I don't see much of a choice except splitting the strings. One thing you might consider is to create a background normalized table, i.e. store the split strings in a relational table while retaining the original production data structure.  I imagine this won't be fast, and it would need to be re-run every time you need an updated data set but it would allow this sort of query, as well as anything else that needs the individual codes.

Comment: @Marcus or (and I don't even like suggesting this) you could pivot your `Ref1` table into 514 fields and use 514 `like` statements.  Seems monstrously inefficient but I'm not sure it would be slower than string splitting.